# The position of "based on the X" phrase

Tags: word-order

I wrote:

> In the Prague treebank, a specific language called PML **based on XML** has been developed, which provides a scheme for annotation of various information.

Can I use *based on XML* in that position?

Or should I say:

> In the Prague treebank, a specific language called PML  has been developed **based on XML**, which provides a scheme for annotation of various information.

Comment: Both are correct. But if I have to choose, I will go with the first: *In the Prague treebank, a specific language called PML,* ***based on XML***, *has been developed which provides a scheme for annotation of various information.*

Comment: *which provides a scheme for annotation of various information.* is a relative clause, so you can not use a comma before "which"

Comment: @Usernew I thought if I use *which* clause as non-restrictive I can use comma

Comment: Ahmad you are correct about the non-restrictive "which".  But the sentence will then have  a lot of commas (note that the two commas before and after **based on XML** are needed to set it off as a parenthetical phrase. Otherwise it would not be clear that the "which " refers to PML and not to XLML.)

Comment: @Ahmad I have provided the best example to go with. :)

Comment: I think, like most of your questions, it would depend on your intended meaning. If I guess the intended meaning correctly, you may want to consider this as an alternative: *In the Prague treebank, a specific **XML-based** language called PML has been developed **to provide** a scheme for annotation of various information.*

Answer (score 1):

Both are fine, but the position now affects which word the relative clause "which...informtion" modifies.

In the second example, clearly the relatve clause is modifying XML, while in the first it seems it is modifying PML.

Comment: Thank you, then I should use first choice as *which* clause modifies PML.

Answer (score 1):

Either of your suggested phrasings would be acceptable. But If you wish to convey unambiguously that the "annotation" is a feature of PML rather than of  XML, I suggest:

- In the Prague treebank a language called PML, which provides a scheme for annotation of various information, has been developed based on XML.

Comment: Paraphrasing like this alters the centre of the message. The focus point of the message is "something has been developed based on something".           If the focus point is what PML can provide, i believe the relative clause should remain at its end position.